# Как правильно работать с SASS (BEM) в Angular 4?

Tags: angularjs, sass, бэм, angular4

Этот код работает, но "_grid.scss" загружается в head с каждым выполняемым компонентом. В других случаях в scss файле компонента его не видно.
Как мне подключить вспомогательные SASS-библиотеки в проект правильно?

header.component.scss

```
@import '../../scss/partials/_variables.scss';
@import '../../scss/partials/_grid.scss';

.main-header{
    width: 100%;
    background: $black;
    color: $white;
    min-height: 3rem;
    &__wrapper{
        @extend .container;
        @extend .flex-grid;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Фрагмент angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "src/scss"
    ]
```

styles.scss

```
@import "scss/partials/_normalize.scss";
```

Comment: Можно еще немного подробностей? Либо я устал, либо вопрос нуждается в уточнении. Как происходит сборка проекта и подключение sass файлов? Это один scss монолит или import './styles.scss' в каждый отдельный компонент?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. У меня есть ряд SCSS файлов, которые разложены по соответствующим папкам (modules, partials...). Раньше я их собирал в одну связку через import. В angular так не выходит, так как я не имею доступа к этим файлам из SCSS файлов компонентов. Я новичок в Angular, если что)

Comment: "вспомогательные SASS-библиотеки", это библиотеки из node_modules, которые нужно подключить? 
Или нужно подключить `_grid.scss` к каждому отдельному файлу, который описывает стили ангуляровского компонента? 

PS у меня подозрение, что проблема далеко не в ангуляре. PPS Я ангуляр не знаю совсем, но если проблема не в нем, я постараюсь помочь

Comment: Это не библиотеки из node_modules. Это мои файлы, с помощью которых мне нужно расширять стили компонентов через @extend. На данный момент я делаю их импорт в каждый компонент, но в браузере они загружаются в head с каждым импортом.

Comment: Если нужно глобально подключить какой-то файл к каждому файлу, можно вставить такую строчку в `stylePreprocessorOptions`: 

`data: '@import "scss/partials/_normalize.scss";'`

Суть этой строчки, что препроцессор вставляет в каждый подключаемый файл эту строку перед обработкой. Я правильно понял задачу?

Comment: Задачу вроде поняли правильно, но строчка эта у меня в проекте ничего не меняет. Как только убираю "grid.scss" из компонента и дописываю его в конфиг компилятор выдает ошибку. Вы могли бы кинуть линк, где можно поподробнее почитать про stylePreprocessorOptions? Ничего не могу найти, кроме как о "includePaths".

Comment: https://github.com/sass/node-sass Вот тут все опции. Этот параметр нужно как-то "вычислить". Потому что у меня похожая задача стояла и решил я ее не сразу. Тут только метод проб и ошибок

Comment: Мой webpack конфиг выглядит так: 

```
data:      `@import "${path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css/_common.scss')}";`,
```

Но это js файл, а не json. Поэтому могут быть проблемы с настройкой подобного